# Implementing Telegram bot webhooks in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, bots, telegram, cfml

I am developing an application in ColdFusion (CFML) to create generic, stateful, bots to be run on the Telegram messaging platform. I've found so far plenty of examples in PHP, some in other languages (Ruby,...), none in CFML. So, here I am.

The "getUpdates"  (i.e., polling) way runs like a breeze, but it's not feasible  polling the Telegram server for new updates  at a rate decent for interactive use (some 30 sec). So, I've turned to Webhooks.

I will go over the webhook setting for a self-signed certificate, it's out of scope here, but I am ready to explain how I did overcome the issue.
My problem is: how to decode the posts received from Telegram server on occurrence of an update?

What my application server (ColdFusion + Tomcat + Apache2) gets from Telegram is an HTTP with an header like this:

```
struct

accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 344
content-type: application/json
host: demo.bigopen.eu
```

and a content section like this:

```
binary

1233411711210097116101951.....  (*cut*)
```

Please note that the data section (ASCII)  contains only decimal digits, not hex. I've been struggling how to decode that stuff, I'm striving to get a JSON representation of a single message.

I've been trying to use the CFML tools I have, such as `BinaryDecode()`, `CharsetEncode()`, Java GZip libraries, etc. but no success so far. I was expecting some serialized JSON in the reply, but it's encoded in a way I cannot decode.  I've found no hint in the literature, since only calls to language-specific libraries (such as `file_get_contents` for PHP) are shown.

I don't expect to be given the actual CFML code, but hopefully what kind of encoding is performed by the Telegram side.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to inform that after some effort I could be able to have this issue solved. Encoding is handled by ColdFusion itself. The data given back by Telegram in a Webhook update is binary, and CF treats them as ByteArray (actually, they're declared as "Array" but not directly addressable). Nonetheless, the `ToString()` function, if applied, returns a string fully valid.

So, the first thing to do is :

```
<cfset reply = DeserializeJSON(ToString(StructFind(GetHttpRequestData(), "content"))) >
```

BTW, `StructFind()` just extracts the "content" section by the structure returned by `GetHttpRequestData()`.
After that, reply is a structure holding what is needed, such as :

```
<cfset message_id = reply.message.message_id />
<cfset message_text = reply.message.text  />
```

and so on.
Hoping that it may be useful to anyone.

Comment: I could not have the CFML code included, it is automatically cut after posting....

Comment: When you are adding code you need to add 4 spaces to the beginning of the line for StackOverflow formatting. I have edited your answer